# Does the current HipHop PHP a php2C++ translator or a JIT?

Tags: php, compilation, virtual-machine, jit, hiphop

I have been searching for documentation of HipHop, and found the paper [The HipHop Compiler for PHP](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2384658) which describes a compilation approach from PHP to C++ statically.

While, in the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php) it says this is a virtual machine and does JIT dynamically.

How can I use the static compilation given the current code base?

Thank you.

Comment: HipHop Virtual Machine (HHVM) !== HipHop compiler (HPHPc), they're two different creatures

Comment: Thanks. So far, I could only find HHVM from the github. Is HPHPc's code still public available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HipHop started out with a static (a.k.a. ahead of time, AOT) compiler. Over time, this approach turned out to be undesirable and a VM with JIT compiler, HHVM, was developed under the same name and in the same repo. The static compiler, HPHPc, as well as a related interpreter, HPHPi, was phased out. This has happened over the last year or so at least. By now, everything but HHVM has been dropped completely and even mentions of it in the wiki at GitHub have been removed. The last revision that still mentioned it is two months old: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Home/bb5c90c860bf87315c1981641c2aa5a318192a9a#hhvm-versus-older-hiphop-execution-engines

HipHop currently contains only one PHP implementation, which is a JIT compiler.